# Author of todo in Meteor todoapp

Tags: javascript, meteor

Dears, please advise how to display author for each todo correctly.
I added authorId to the Todos collection, made helper and corrected publication, but it doesn't work: I see profile of author in browser, but don't know how to pass the name to todo.

I guess that the issue in todoArgs(todo) in https://github.com/meteor/todos/blob/master/imports/ui/components/lists-show.js because todoAuthor isn't passed.

Hope on any help/comment.

todos.js

```
Todos.helpers({
   todoAuthor: function() {
      return Meteor.users.findOne(this.authorId);
   }
});
```

publications.js

```
children: [{
  find(list) {
    return Todos.find({ listId: list._id }, { fields: Todos.publicFields });
  },
  children: [
  {
     find: function(username, list) {
      return Meteor.users.find(
        { _id: username.authorId },
        { fields: { profile: 1 } });
     }
    }
  ]
}],
```

todos-item.html

```
<template name="Todos_item">
    {{todoAuthor.profile.name}}
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the temporary solution using {{#let}}, but it would be nice to hear best practice on that matter. Thank you.